# Why is function $X \mapsto z^T X z$ linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, scalar-fields

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook):

> $\textsf{Example 2.7}\;\;$ The positive semidefinite cone $\mathbf{S}_+^n$ can be expressed as
>
> $$ \bigcap_{z\not=0} \{ X \in \mathbf{S}^n \mid z^TXz \geq 0 \}. $$
>
> For each $z \not= 0$, $z^TXz$ is a (not identically zero) linear function of $X$, so the sets
>
> $$ \{ X \in \mathbf{S}^n \mid z^TXz \geq 0 \} $$
>
> are, in fact, halfspaces in $\mathbf{S}^n$. Thus the positive semidefinite cone is the intersection of an infinite number of halfspaces, and so is convex.

<sub>[[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLtGL.png)]</sub>

---

Why is $z^T X z$ a linear function in matrix $X$? I don't understand what to do when the variable is a matrix.

Comment: Can you expand $z^T(X+Y)z$?

Comment: Or rather, my question is, what is the intuition behind this being linear? For a line, I can draw mx+b=y. I have no idea what this means for it to be linear

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it is boyd convex optimization

Comment: Does it not simply mean that $z^T(aX+bY)z = az^TXz+bz^TYz$?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414)

Comment: The intuition is when you do all the matrix multiplications then you will get a linear combination of the entries of $X$ with some coefficients. It will not have, for example, the entries of $X$ squared, or some other operations on them.

Comment: Okay, your y=mx+b comment indicates that there's a gap in your math knowledge. You could probably go read an article or two (Wikipedia, Wolfram math world, ...) on "linear algebra" and "linear operators". A full class would be best, but you should at least be familiar with the terms and concepts. I promise you that they will come up frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your matrix $X$ is like a container of variables, and you can write :

$$z^\top X z = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N z_i z_j X_{ij}$$

As you can see, the function $f(X)$ is linear in the variables $X_{ij}$ which are contained in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ {\bf X} \mapsto {\bf z}^\top {\bf X} \, {\bf z} = \mbox{tr} \left( {\bf z}^\top {\bf X} \, {\bf z} \right) = \mbox{tr} \left( {\bf z} \, {\bf z}^\top {\bf X} \right) = \langle {\bf z} \, {\bf z}^\top , {\bf X} \rangle$$

where the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) is used.

Answer (score 0):

The key point to note is that the quadratic form $z^T X z$ is linear **in $X$** (to be explicit, it is not linear **in $z$**). To verify this, the additivity and homogeneity tests yield:

(i) $z^T (X + Y) z = z^TXz + z^TYz$

(ii) $z^T (\alpha X)z = \alpha (z^TXz)$
which helps us conclude that the given expression is indeed linear in $X$.

Comment: How can it be linear and quadratic at the same time?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it depends on what you view the expression as a function of. If viewed as a function of $X$, it is linear (i.e. $f(X) = z^TXz$). On the other hand, if you view it as a function of $z$, for some fixed $X$, then it is not linear, it is a quadratic form. Hope this clarifies.